# JIRA/V1 Integration: Null exception thrown when attempting to create a ticket in V1

Tags: jira, versionone

Is there a way to map V1 required fields to JIRA fields & vis versa through the JIRA/VersionOne Integration Service?

Backstory:
The following error is being generated in the service for each JIRA ticket attempting to be created in V1.

**Error during saving workitems: Bad Request: NULL**

**Error trying to create Workitem in VersionOne for [/DEFECTS-6] Test in JIRA:**

**System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

We believe this to be caused by required fields in V1 not being filled out.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to add additional required fields would be to alter the source code of the integration.

One thing that you could do is to check what fields are currently set as required in your VersionOne workspace, perhaps something was marked as being required that is causing this issue.

Another thing to check is that all the priority field values that you are using actually exist in each system, and that you have them mapped correctly.